# Typescript declaration file doesn't include other declaration file references

Tags: typescript

I built a TypeScript library that is the "Core" to my application (call it Core.ts) using internal modules and a single class per file approach compiled to a single output file(Core.js). I added `--declaration` flag to compiler and it generates the declaration file (Core.d.ts). Problem is, this generated declaration file didn't include the references to other declaration files originally included in the compilation. Once I add the generated Core.d.ts to my project I get something like 1k errors about undefined `JQuery`, `Backbone`, etc... coming from that file.

I have the comments flag set to true and it generated the comments and references in Core.js but stripped them all away for Core.d.ts

If I look at other definition files I grabbed from Definitely Typed some do include references to other definition files so this seems like a bug that the compiler is stripping them away despite comments flag being set to true.

Please advise.

Seems this issue has been encountered but never looked into:

https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/434018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are expecting `Core.d.ts` to include the definitions from `jquery.d.ts` and `backbone.d.ts` but I think conceptually the TypeScript compiler expects you to reference all three:

```
///<reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
///<reference path="backbone.d.ts" />
///<reference path="Core.d.ts" />
```

A typical example of this are jQuery plugins - each definition file contains the definition of the plugin, but not of jQuery, so you need to reference both `jquery.d.ts` and `jquery.someplugin.d.ts`.

**Update**

Actually - I think you are just expecting the reference comment to be included in `Core.d.ts` - this makes more sense. I'm going to comment on the bug on CodePlex that you linked to, maybe it will wake the discussion up!

Comment: Thanks Steve, I hope it will as the workaround is quite annoying. (Compile -> Manually add refs > Remove --declaration flag so next compile doesn't overwrite -> Run -> Re-add --declaration flag and repeat process with any changes to library). I might try to set up a better workaround by prepending a _dependencies.ts file post compile.